# How to maintain consistency after deleting first row in table. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table named Suppliers and I want to delete the first row:

```
delete from suppliers where supplierID = 1
```

What does it mean to, "Do whatever is necessary to maintain consistency" after the prior query? The Primary Key (SupplierID) was created using the AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Consistency can be disrupted only if you have a dependent table with foreign keys, relevant to suppliers.

Comment: Through code, is there a way to handle this situation? I know the key may be reference else ware, hence, I have an orphan record

Comment: In InnoDB you can use ON DELETE CASCADE to automatically delete the dependent records. In MyISAM you'll have to manually delete them.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you are using AUTO_INCREMENT then you cant do what you are thinking as AUTO_INCREMENT keys in database are used to uniquely identify a given row. The best what you can do to find the lowest unused key value is that don't use AUTO_INCREMENT at all, and manage your keys manually.

Also to mention that you can use ON DELETE CASCADE to automatically delete the dependent records in InnoDB database however in MyISAM you have to manually delete them.

Also check this [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Answer (score 0):

To maintain cosistency you should use InnoDB endine and foreign keys in dependent tables pointing to `Suppliers.supplierID`.

Then database will issue an error if you will try to delete record which is referenced in any other table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

ID of first supplier can be found this way:

```
SELECT MIN( supplierID ) FROM Suppliers
```